# Struts2.5.10:: Map values are not being set to Model Driven Bean

Tags: struts2, struts2-interceptors

In our jsp file, we have attributes Map object as defined in the code snippet below, the values of which are not being set in the Model Driven Bean during an ajax call which gets invoked onChange. Can someone help me in understanding this issue and how to get it resolved?

Let me know if anymore info is needed.

This code worked absolutely fine with the old Struts v2.0.6 and xwork v2.0.1.

I am currently having Struts2 v.2.5.10 and I have removed the dependency for xwork jars as the current struts2 has it already bundled as a package inside it.

```
<select name="attributes['language']" id="language" class="custom-form-control" onchange="ajaxAction(this.form,'setCFS_addPesOption.action?enterpriseSection=PesService');">
    <option value="" selected="selected">--select--</option>
    <option value="NL">NL</option>
    <option value="FR">FR</option>
    <option value="DE">DE</option>
    <option value="EN">EN</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You've migrated a project from `Struts 2.0.6` (***2007***) to Struts `2.5.10` (***2017***), crossing FOUR minor versions, along *a decade* of bugfixes, improvements and changes of every kind... and you expect the code to work *as-is* ?? C'mon man, 2.0.6!... George W. Bush was still POTUS back then O_o

Comment: haha...I know I got my hands on it now as I recently started working on this application. But, I seriously do not understand why this is happening. Its a bit strange to me

Comment: I was serious too. Big improvements occurred around 2.1.6, 2.1.8, 2.3.15.3 and definitely 2.5. No DMI anymore, no action prefix anymore, a different filter etc... also ModelDriven is dumb, it was there for Struts1 lovers, I think it's time to consider rethinking the application, if you want to port it to newer versions. Otherwise, keep that old stuff as is, and go far as much as you can from it :)

Comment: What do you suggest could be the solution? I see no errors in the logs to debug this issue.

Comment: I see that the Hashtable element i.e. attributes is returned as empty in the bean.

Comment: I am ready to refactor the code to get this working. But, I really need some ray of hope.

Comment: Struts configuration ? Interceptor Stack ? Ajax js function ? I'm pretty sure it's too broad, but just for curiosity, edit your question if you want

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132573/struts2-no-longer-accepts-http-map-parameters. Thanks for your time and support :)

Comment: Nice, and good luck :)